# Can't decipher error from linker

Tags: c++, gcc

My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/WWWyNqGM) and is in a file called new.cpp

I get the following error at the console:

```
[usr@host dir]$ gcc new.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccVKDKZm.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
new.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
new.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea how to debug this - any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `g++ new.cpp`... ?

Comment: What are you attempting to do?  Calling gcc or g++ without options builds an executable binary, but you have no real `int main` defined to execute.

Comment: Mkae sure you turn on all the appropriate warnings and treat them as real problems: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -ansi new.cpp`

Comment: @HostileFork the GCC frontend `gcc` is clever enough to look at the file's extension, and compile as C++. That does not mean it will link correctly though :)

Comment: @rubenvb Frontend, yes...but if you want your "a.out"...!  *(This is why all my programs are named a.cpp ... `-o` is for suckas.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you have is a link error, your code compiled fine. The error is telling you it is unable to link to some standard library elements.

The reason you have got this is because you are compiler C++ with the gcc C frontend, well actually gcc will compile it as C++ but then will not link it against the C++ std lib.

The solution is simple, use the c++ front end, g++

```
g++ new.cpp
```

Comment: @Froskoy excellent, glad to be of help. (if you could mark it as correct then this question can help others with the same error in the future).

Answer (score 0):

```
int main();
```

declares a `main`, but doesn't define one. Try

```
int main() {}
```

instead, and it compiles (but with warnings about signed/unsigned comparisons) and links without problems when compiled with g++.

On line 37, did you intend

```
queue >>= bsize;
```

instead of

```
queue >> bsize;
```

?